# How to use synchronize in Capybara exactly?

Tags: ruby, rspec, capybara, browser-automation

If how to  use wait_until is pretty clear (I've used the methods like this while creating tests through the native Webdriver methods), but not the new synchronize method (sorry:)). I've read the theme about why wait_until is deprecated, I've read the article about that, I've read the docs with method description and also read the code where the description present too. But I didn't find any example or tutorial how exactly to use this method.

Anybody, please, provide few cases where I (and maybe someone else) could see and learn how to use this method

For example the case

```
expect(actual).to equal(expected)
```

where should I "put" synchronize method to get negative exception only after timeout had been passed?

UPD: For those who interested please look into this links:

http://www.elabs.se/blog/53-why-wait_until-was-removed-from-capybara

https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara/blob/master/lib/capybara/node/base.rb#L44

Comment: Do `Capybara::RSpecMatchers` work in your case? They do autowaiting

Comment: You're right they should but my tests are failing with no such element (or smth like this:)) exception, without waiting the specified period of time

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I just found a case where I needed to use #synchronize. I have a helper method which looks for an element on the page and if it exists it clicks on it and returns some text that gets updated on the page (via JavaScript). There are cases where between finding the element and clicking on it, it might disappear (and possibly re-appear) due to other JavaScript code and could raise a Selenium::WebDriver::Error::StaleElementReferenceError exception. So I use synchronize like this:

```
page.document.synchronize do
  element = first('#whatever')
  if element
    element.click
    find('#foo').text
  else
    nil
  end
end
```

Comment: Actually everything should be fine even without synchronize as Capybara itself reloads elements when `click` or `text` are invoked and error occurs.

Comment: @AndreyBotalov yes.  I keep reading that, over and over again.  You don't need `wait_until` or `synchronize` or `sleep`s.  And yet, I keep running into pages where I absolutely do because the tests fail otherwise.  Simple assertions like `expect(page).to have_css("whatever")` fail on slower Windows machines until I either put a `sleep 1` in front of them or wrap them in a `synchronize`.  I get that this should not be true, and if I can find out why it is I'll happily submit a patch to the Capybara devs.  But meanwhile, we need this stuff documented.

Comment: @MarkReed Actually I wasn't familiar enough with some parts of Capybara source code at the time of writing previous comment. Reloading happens in `Capybara::Node::Element#reload` if `allow_reload` is `true`. But `@allow_reload` is set to true only by `find`, not `first` or `all`. The proper way to fix this in Capybara is to fix `all` (though I think that would require some refactoring). The workaround fix for issue with `first` is to add code to `allow_reload` for `first` method.

Comment: `Simple assertions like expect(page).to have_css("whatever") fail on slower Windows machines` - Probably you should increase `default_wait_time`

Comment: But aren't we then back to the same situation as inserting `sleep`s, effectively?  Also, do assertions like `have_css` wind up calling `find` or some other method? (I guess I could read the source..)

Comment: @MarkReed `have_css` doesn't need to set `allow_reload`

Comment: The reasons not to use `sleep`s are: 1. Make your code slower even when machine is fast. 2. Clutter code

Comment: Damn, this method really works! I spent around 20 hours (totally) to find the problem. I don't know why author of Capybara avoid to not use this method.

Answer (score 3):

See this helper method that might help you. Found at https://gist.github.com/10c41024510ee9f235e0

```
# spec/support/capybara_helpers.rb

module CapybaraHelpers
  def wait_for_whizboo
    start = Time.now
    while true
      break if [check for whizboo here, e.g. with page.evaluate_script]
      if Time.now > start + 5.seconds
        fail "Whizboo didn't happen."
      end
      sleep 0.1
    end
  end
end

RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.include CapybaraHelpers, type: :request
end
```

Comment: There is a set of some cases to workaround this method but the #synchronize method was created to wait for changes on the page by Capybara author, so I would be glad to learn how to use it