# Cucumber Capybara Selenium race condition with expect(all())

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, selenium, cucumber, capybara

I am working on a Rails 4 app. In the app, there is a page with a modal form whose behavior I am trying to test as follows:

1. Click a link to open the modal,
2. Click a link to add a `<li>` form via JS
3. Input some field data, submit via JS
4. See the populated form item is present
5. Click a link to add another `<li>` form via JS
6. Input some more field data, submit via JS
7. See the populated form item is present
8. Confirm the correct number of `<li>` elements

My web_step for counting the number of `<li>` elements uses an `expect(all())` RSpec expectation like so:

```
Then(/^I should see the number of items equals "(.*?)"$/) do |number_of_ items |
    expect(all(:xpath, xpath_items).length).to eq(number_of_ items.to_i)
end
```

`xpath_items` is collecting the elements correctly.

**The Problem**

I am getting intermittent cucumber test failures.  I think Capybara is looking for the `<li>` elements to count (and failing) before JS has changed them in the DOM.  I think `expect(all())` is the culprit, but not sure the best way to refactor or make it work consistently.

**Failed Fixes**

I have tried to fix this race condition via a few methods, including (1) increasing `Capybara.default_wait_time = 120`, (2) adding `sleep(10)` to web_steps (an anti-pattern I think), (3) wrapping web_step functionality in `page.document.synchronize` as shown in
[How to use synchronize in Capybara exactly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14588241/how-to-use-synchronize-in-capybara-exactly)

I know `wait_until` method is removed from Capybara as shown [here.](http://www.elabs.se/blog/53-why-wait_until-was-removed-from-capybara)

Stack: rails 4.0.3, cucumber 1.5.15, capybara 2.2.1, selenium-webdriver 2.41.0, angular.js, jquery, bootstrap. FWIW…my machine is a Retina MacBook Pro i7, so pretty fast.

Any ideas appreciated.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Capybara provides options (:count, :minimum, :maxium, :between) for specifying how many elements to wait for. Assuming you are using the latest version of Capybara, these can now be used in `all`.

By specifying the `:count`, you can tell the `all` method to wait for a specific number of items to appear. This could be added to your step as:

```
Then(/^I should see the number of items equals "(.*?)"$/) do |number_of_ items|
  expect(all(:xpath, xpath_items, count: number_of_ items.to_i).length).to eq(number_of_ items.to_i)
end
```

However, this seems a bit hard to read to me. I would suggest switching to using a `have_selector`, which does support these options. With this, you could simplify the step to:

```
Then(/^I should see the number of items equals "(.*?)"$/) do |number_of_ items|
  expect(page).to have_selector(:xpath, xpath_items, count: number_of_ items.to_i)
end
```